Connecting to Flask Server(APIS)
I am building a weather and mood app. I got the weather API and openai. I used kivy for front end and flask for the sever side but i am having issues connecting the APIs with my flask server. I am using port 5000 but i keep getting the error: port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /get_weather (Caused by NewConnectionError<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000029E326172C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: WinError (i couldn't copy the full error message). Here is my code for the flask server:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from waitress import serve
import requests
import logging
import openai
import mysql.connector
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()

openai.api_key = os.getenv('sk-None-tERLK1wAN9fG1Gyk7YaWT3BlbkFJJ4CcYCFuGzS4z4XaoqvF')

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="moodmate",
    password="Amarachi1994",
    database="mysql",  
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

weather_api_key = os.getenv('84155c096c95493fbaa141101242107')


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://moodmate:Amarachi1994@localhost/moodmate'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.username}>'

@app.route('/get_weather', methods=['POST'])
def get_weather():
    data = request.json
    city = data.get('city')

    if not city:
        return jsonify({'error': 'City is required'}), 400

    url = f'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key={weather_api_key}&q={city}'
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        weather_info = {
            "location": data['location']['name'],
            "status": data['current']['condition']['text'],
            "temperature": data['current']['temp_c'],
            "humidity": data['current']['humidity'],
            "wind_speed": data['current']['wind_kph'] / 3.6  # Convert kph to m/s
        }
        return jsonify(weather_info)
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to retrieve weather data'}), response.status_code

@app.route('/analyze_mood', methods=['POST'])
def analyze_mood():
    user_input = request.json.get('message')
    conversation_history = request.json.get('history', [])
    user_mood = request.json.get('mood')

    conversation_history.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})

    positive_emotions = ["Happy", "Love", "Gratitude", "Anticipation", "Compassion", "Empathy"]
    user_emotions = {
        "Sad": "sad",
        "Depressed": "depressed",
        "Disgust": "disgust",
        "Anger": "anger",
        "Horror": "horror",
        "Shame": "shame",
        "Anxiety": "anxiety",
        "Fear": "fear",
        "Empathy": "empathy",
        "Pity": "pity",
        "Boredom": "boredom",
        "Entrancement": "entrancement",
        "Interest": "interest",
        "Pride": "pride"
    }

    mood_response = ""

    if user_mood == "Positive":
        mood_response = f"Great. You must be in a great mood. ({user_input})"
        if user_input in positive_emotions:
            mood_response += " How about you spread your happiness to others?"
    elif user_mood == "Negative":
        mood_response = f"Sorry to hear that you're feeling down ({user_input}). How about you tell me about it, I will listen to you?"
    else:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=conversation_history
        )
        mood_response = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']

    conversation_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": mood_response})

    return jsonify({
        'reply': mood_response,
        'history': conversation_history
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create database tables if they don't exist
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    logging.debug("Starting Flask server ...")
    serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)


Please, what do i do?
I thought i could resolve the issue using MySQl Server but it did not work. I uninstalled my .env and installed another one, then installed all dependencies, yet, nothing worked. Before I was using MySQL port 3306, and 127.0.0.1 but it did not work, so I had to change it to 0.0.0.0, port-5000. It still did not work. Please, I need help. This is my first project and I will greatly appreciate al the help i can get.
